# Disable search in Sonata Admin

Tags: symfony, sonata-admin, symfony-sonata

How can I disable the search feature in Sonata Admin Bundle, in order to not show the search input field in the upper menu?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need to override the **standard_layout.html.twig** template and overwrite the block **sonata_top_bar_search** with nothing in it. That will make it disappear.

```
sonata_admin:
    templates:
        layout:  YourBundle::layout.html.twig
```

Read more [here](http://sonata-project.org/bundles/admin/master/doc/reference/templates.html) about customizing templates.

Comment: Thanks! I thought there will be a parameter or something similar, but this seems to be the only option so far.

Comment: As mentioned below by @monofone: "In later version (2.3+) ist the block sonata_sidebar_search that needs to be overwritten."

Answer (score 7):

In Sonata Admin version >= 3.0 it's as simple as:

```
sonata_admin:
    search: false
```

in your `config/packages/sonata_admin.yaml`.

Comment: The cleanest solution on this post

Comment: AFAIK there was no such option at the time.

Answer (score 5):

Just complementing the answers here, the complete solution:

config.yml

```
sonata_admin:
    templates:
        layout:  AppBundle::layout.html.twig
```

AppBundle::layout.html.twig

```
{% extends 'SonataAdminBundle::standard_layout.html.twig' %}

{% block sonata_sidebar_search %}
{% endblock sonata_sidebar_search %}
```

Answer (score 3):

In later version (2.3+) ist the block **sonata_sidebar_search** that needs to be overwritten.

Comment: This is more suited as a comment on the answer.

Comment: Yes, you are right but I can`t comment due to reputation.